# Unable to connect to ApsaraDB for MongoDB instance via Internet

Tags: database, mongodb, alibaba-cloud

I have created a ApsaraDB for MongoDB instance in Alibaba Cloud I have even generated MongoDB connection string for both shell and clients. But I am not able to connect

connection string for shell: mongo mongodb://root:****@dds-6gj54086e0c157941456-pub.mongodb.ap-south-1.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717,dds-6gj54086e0c157942992-pub.mongodb.ap-south-1.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717/admin?replicaSet=mgset-1050000641

connection string for clients: mongodb://root:****@dds-6gj54086e0c157941456-pub.mongodb.ap-south-1.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717,dds-6gj54086e0c157942992-pub.mongodb.ap-south-1.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717/admin?replicaSet=mgset-1050000641

I am sure that I am using the correct password. Am  i missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the instance be part of a Security Group with proper inbound rules.

Comment: With the description he gave, I'm not able to give a more complete answer. So, trying to help, I asked if he tried to add it to a SG, one of the classic mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, ApsaraDB for MongoDB does not support access through the Internet. You can only connect to ApsaraDB for MongoDB from an ECS instance in the region where the ApsaraDB for MongoDB instance resides.

Please find the official information in Docs below,
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/faq-detail/39944.htm

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no support to access the instance via the internet. You can only connect to ApsaraDB for MongoDB from an ECS instance in the region where the ApsaraDB for MongoDB instance resides.

This is clearly stated in their Product FAQ Section, Please have a look at [Official Documentation](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/faq-detail/39944.htm)